# Use of did + two verbs

Tags: past-tense

When making a question in the past tense using *did* and two verbs do you write the second verb in the past or present tense?

> Example:
>   Did you call and **cancel** the appointment yesterday?
>
> or:
>    Did you call and **canceled** the appointment yesterday?

Does *did* apply only to the first verb, in this case *call*, or does it also apply to *cancel* and I do not have to write the second verb in past tense?

Comment: No, just one auxiliary. Did you call and cancel the appointment?

Comment: They should always be in the same tense. Did you [call and cancel]? Have you [called and cancelled]?

Comment: The auxiliary verb "did" has scope over the coordination "call and cancel", and it requires that both verbs must be plain forms.

Comment: @Davo Yes, but "call" and "cancel" are not tensed forms - they are plain (infinitive) forms.

Comment: @BillJ - Wouldn't ***did*** effectively apply via parallel construction (or something like that) as *Did you call and (did you) cancel,* so that the word *call* is infinitive, but the usage of *did call* (and *(did cancel)* ) is tensed?

Comment: @Davo, you are right, but the tensed bit is "did". As billJ said, "call" and "cancel" are both infinitives.

Answer (score 1):

The auxiliary verb "do" is the only part that needs to be conjugated.  The rest of the linked verbs are all *bare infinitives*.

> Did you **feed** and **water** the horses this morning?
>
> Did you **wash, dry, and wax** the car like I asked?

You can think of this as a shortened form, rather than needing to ask separate questions, removing any repeated words:

> **Did you call** and **did you cancel** the appointment?
>   ⇒ **Did you call** and **cancel** the appointment?